# Custom WordPress menu output (wrapping parent links in span)

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I'm trying to implement a responsive jQuery navigation but I need to extend the default output of the WP menu. I need to wrap any pages that have children with a span and remove the link. For example:

```
        <nav id="menu-right">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>Friends</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Alexa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Alexander</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fred</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">James</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jefferson</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jordan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Meagan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Melissa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nicole</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Samantha</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Scott</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span>Family</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Adam</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ben</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bruce</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Eddie</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jack</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">John</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Martina</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Matthew</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Olivia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Owen</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span>Work colleagues</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">David</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dennis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Eliza</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Larry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lisa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Michael</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rachelle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rick</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should override Walker_Nav_Menu http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Nav_Menus/Walker_Nav_Menu.html , http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function

Comment: I have to say... after reading up on custom walker output, I'm rather confused! It seems to be what I want, I'm just not quite sure how to leverage it.